# How to work with BCP

Tags: sql-server

I am connecting to sql server which is in another server from my server.

I am executing the following:

```
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from databasename.dbo.tablename " 
queryout "D:\tempexportfile.txt" -c -t, -T -S[Connected servername]'
```

it is writing the text file in the connected server from my server, but i want to the text file is in my server,

Is there any posibility to specify my current server and write text file here?

Answer (score 1):

On the server that you execute the bcp on should connect via a share drive to your server. Then replace the D:\ with the share drive letter.

Another way is to make sure that you have a share on your server that is accessible from the SQL Server, then replace the D:\ with \yourservername\sharename.

Hope that helps.